# Trying to rotate object when key pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to make the ability to slide in an FPS game I'm working on and I've tried rotating the player object but when tested, it does nothing. Pressing the slide key I have assigned does nothing but rotate the player object in the Y and Z axis (I'm trying to rotate it on the X axis)

Here's the code I'm using (only relevant parts have been kept in):

```cs
public class SlideMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rig;
    public CapsuleCollider capcol;
    public GameObject player;

    public float originalHeight;
    public float reducedHeight;

    public float slideSpeed = 10f;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        capcol = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        originalHeight = capcol.height;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            Sliding();
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            GoUp();
    }

    private void Sliding()
    {
        capcol.height = reducedHeight;
        player.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(1.599f, 0f, 0f);
        rig.AddForce(transform.forward * slideSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

    }

    private void GoUp()
    {
        GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().height = originalHeight;
        player.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```

I've gotten ZERO error messages from this but I haven't managed to find the problem

**Another problem I've also had** is when you start sliding, it just instantly rotates the Player object to X 1.599 Y 0 Z 0. I want it to rotate to where the player is facing but I haven't found a way to do it, even using `transform.foward` or other references won't work.

Answer (score 0):

### The Explanation (skip to script if you want) (read notes)

I reccomend using Quaternion's methods. You can use Quaternion.Slerp which can smooth out the rotation towards the player.

- Slerp means spherical linear interpolation

Basically, Slerp is a 3 argumented method. the first argument is the current rotation, the second argument is the target rotation, and the third is at which point between those two you want to output.

More simply, Lerp is linear interpolation. Lerps arguments are the same, except it handles floats and not Quaternions. If you Mathf.Lerp(0,1,1); you will get 1, because 1 is all the ay to the second argument. If you do Mathf(0, 3, 0.5); you will get 1.5 because 1.5 is halfway (0.5) between them both.

You can imagine slerp like that, if you give rotation (90, 0, 0) and alerp it to (0, 0, 0) by 0.5 you will get (45, 0, 0).

On this example, I slerp from the current rotation, to the target rotation, by delta time. This way, as time goes on, it slightly increases the current rotation to be the target.

I can create the target as 1.599 rotated on the x.

To make this relative **Make a parent game object to the player containing the mesh and rigidbody and maybe the collider (depends if you want the collider upright).** I will call this "slidePlayer" slidePlayer must be a child of the player gameObject

### Notes

- Make sure to have slidePlayer to a gameObject that is a child of player, but **must** have the player mesh **or sliding won't be visible**.
- Change rot to the **target rotation**.
- Change speed to **speed to rotate to the target rotation.**

Here is your script I changed:

```
public class SlideMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rig;
    public CapsuleCollider capcol;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject slidePlayer;

    public float originalHeight;
    public float reducedHeight;

    public float slideSpeed = 10f;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        capcol = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        originalHeight = capcol.height;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            Sliding();
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            GoUp();
    }

    private void Sliding()
    {
        capcol.height = reducedHeight;
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(1.599f, 0f, 0f);
        float speed = 1f;
        Quaternion curRot = slidePlayer.transform.localRotation;
        slidePlayer.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(curRot, rot, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            
        rig.AddForce(transform.forward * slideSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

    }

    private void GoUp()
    {
        GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().height = originalHeight;

        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
        float speed = 3f;
        Quaternion curRot = slidePlayer.transform.localRotation;
        slidePlayer.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(curRot, rot, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Let me know if there are any problems in coments. Thanks.